# The new stocks app keeps on closing by itself

Tags: macos, stocks.app

The new Stocks app in macOS Mojave keeps on closing by itself.

The app closes, not crashes. It happens randomly.

Any way to fix this?

Comment: It hasn't been happening to me.  Your question is at risk of being closed.  See [ask] for tips on asking questions here.

Comment: Does the app close when you choose a specific option? Does it close when idle? Are you using macOS or iOS on what version? Does it close or crash? Can you add relevant lines from the console and/or provide a crash log?

Comment: Latest macOS, it closes, not crashes. 

Happens randomly.

Why the down vote.

Comment: You said, "Latest macOS"; however, with the lack of other information to even begin to diagnose the issue it might be better if you actually said which version number too, e.g 10.14.4.

Comment: Please add your "update" as an answer and select it as the solution because editing the question as you did, doesn't mark this as "solved."

Answer (score 3):

You can try to cleanup/remove preferences etc.

- Quit Stocks (in case it's still running)
- wait a few seconds
- Open Terminal
- Run the following by copy/pasting it into Terminal and pressing Enter

  ```
  rm -r ~/Library/{Group\ ,}Containers/com.apple.stocks
  rm -r ~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.apple.stocks.savedState
  ```
- Run Stocks again

PS: You might get an error `...Library/Group Containers/com.apple.stocks: No such file or directory` which you can ignore (don't have the file on my Mac, but Stocks tries to access it).

Comment: aww will i lose all my watchlist?

Comment: @SuperUberDuper Assuming it‘s stored in one of these files, yes. You *could* try to just delete the last file (saved state) and check whether this already solves the problem. You shouldn’t loose your watchlist in this case.